# Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'AppTheme'

Tags: android, android-studio-2.3

I am migrating from command line compiling (yikes!) using Ant to Android Studio.  I am seeing the error listed in the Title/Subject line and am not sure on how to proceed.  The error comes from a reference to AppTheme.NoActionBar in v21/values-21.xml.  My build.gradle file shows:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "arl.weather.mobile"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
```

Do I need to alter something here/or is the issue elsewhere?

TIA,
steve

My edit-It is dying at the AppTheme reference below (part of v21/values-v21.xml file). I wanted to paste the entire file but when I did the formatting went crazy and was unreadable.  I hope this portion helps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="notification_action_color_filter">@color/secondary_text_default_material_light</color>
    <dimen name="notification_content_margin_start">0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="notification_main_column_padding_top">0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="notification_media_narrow_margin">12dp</dimen>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Since the error is in `v21/values-21.xml`, showing this file is more important than `build.gradle`.

Comment: Can you show your `styles.xml` file(s)?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that Android Studio created `v21/values-21.xml` for you. You should just delete this file and any XML resource files that Android Studio generated.

Comment: Or add the support design dependencies to the Gradle file

Comment: @cricket_007 Isn't `AppTheme` declared in the project itself rather than the Support Library?

Comment: Yeah, just realized, so I added comment above

Comment: Sorry about the delayed response - thanks for everyone's inputs!  Here is the styles.xml file: <code> <resources>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources> </code>   For cricket_007: are you recommending an edit of a build.gradle file?  If so, what precisely should my edit be?  TIA.

Comment: @user3063547 Please [edit] your question to include the file which causes the error. After you copy and paste the code, select it then press Ctrl-K to indent every line an additional 4 spaces to preserve formatting.

Comment: cricket_007 - could you please expand on your suggestion "add the support design dependencies to the Gradle file".

Comment: I solved the problem by deleting the res/values-v21 directory.  Thanks to Code-Apprentice for alluding to this solution earlier!